# How can I define Symfony root directory on shared host?

Tags: .htaccess, symfony, configuration, url-rewriting, shared-hosting

Does somebody has experiences with Symfony on a shared host (Linux).
I am using Symfony on my localhost, it works fine.
I also installed the Apache pack.

When I want to open the website on the webserver, then I have to write www.mywebsite.com/public to see my website. I tried to add this line `DocumentRoot /var/www/project/public` to the .htaccess file (the file is inside the public folder) but this does not make a change. Do not know how to get it work like on localhost. The project on the server is a clone of the project on localhost.

I tried to copy the code from the documentation https://symfony.com/doc/current/setup/web_server_configuration.html into my .htaccess file, but this was not working.

I also tried to move the .htaccess file from the public folder into the root. But then I get a warning message, that I should contact the administrator.

This is my .htaccess file:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php

<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}::$1 ^(/.+)/(.*)::\2$
    RewriteRule ^(.*) - [E=BASE:%1]

    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule ^ - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
    RewriteRule ^index\.php(?:/(.*)|$) %{ENV:BASE}/$1 [R=301,L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
    RewriteRule ^ - [L]

    RewriteRule ^ %{ENV:BASE}/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_alias.c>
        RedirectMatch 307 ^/$ /index.php/
    </IfModule>
</IfModule>
```

Comment: I guess you should not modify any content in the `.htaccess` file, for a default installation. If your shared account can only have one domain, and if the website behind the domain is the symfony app, then access it without `/public`. But if you have a subdomain, only then use the `/public`. And you should look in the `.composer.json` file to see the `symfony_web_dir` to be also `public`. If not, change it to `public` and then `composer dump-autoload -o` to let composer know about it.

Comment: @DanCostinel You mean I should assign my domain not to the Symfony root folder but to the public folder. Just simple as that?

Comment: Hm, tested it. This does not work...

Comment: Obviously, to the `public` folder, not to the Symfony root folder. You app is being accessed by the `app.php` (located in the `public` dir) when your app is online. And yes, is working. If not, then you are doing something else wrongly.

Comment: If my domain is assigned to the root folder of symfony, then I can open www.mypage.com/public and I see my website. But when I assign my domain to the public folder, then I only see a blank page. What could be the reason for this?

Comment: Is it because I am using a subdomain? Actually my domain name is project.mypage.com

Comment: To see what the problem is, you should check the `var/logs/prod.log` file